# How to make code?

Tags: python, arrays, row

I have 3 data.

```
code2 data : code data(ex:a1,b1,c1)
field data : field data(ex:a2,b2,c2)
file data: row data
```

row data format is next line

```
field1|field2|field3
a1    |a2    |value1
a1    |b2    |value2
a1    |c2    |value3
b1    |a2    |value4
b1    |b2    |value5
...
```

I want to make new data. New data format is next line

```
index|a2|b2|c2
a1   |value1|value2|value3
b1   |vlaue4|value5 ...
```

I used numpy and pandas 's array lib but I can't make a newdata

My code is next line

```
f = open('D:\\file.txt','r')
g = open('D:\\code2.txt','r')
h = open('D:\\field.txt','r')
k = open('D:\\data.txt','w')
import numpy as np
a=[]
b=[]
c = [0 for _ in range(102218)]
d = [0 for _ in range(63)]
f_1 = f.readlines()[1:]
g_1 = g.readlines()
h_1 = h.readlines()
for i in range(0,102219):
    c[i]=""
for lineG in g_1:
    a = lineG.split('|')
    code = int(a)
    for lineH in h_1:
        b = lineH.split('|')
        for lineF in f_1:
            z = lineF.split(',')
            if a == z[1] and b == z[2]:
                array1 = np.arange(6542080).reshape(len(lineG),len(lineH))
                array1 = np.array(ro)
                break
            else:
                continue
k.close()
h.close()
g.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: SO is not a free programming service, I recommend you show what you have tried since here we highly value that. Then we can give you suggestions and propose possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `pivot`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
            ['a1','a2','value1']
            ,['a1','b2','value2']
            ,['a1','c2','value3']
            ,['b1','a2','value4']
            ,['b1','b2','value5']
        ]), columns=['field1', 'field2', 'field3'])

df.pivot(index='field1', columns='field2', values='field3')
```

Comment: 원진님 댓글 달아주셔서 감사합니다. 그러나 저런 방법을 했지만 오류가 계속해서 발생합니다. 혹시 이메일 주소를 보내주시면 제가 자세히 알려드리겠습니다.